# Off-topic flagging links should be HTTPS now

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, flagging, https

When flagging a question, most links in the dialog that comes up are now HTTPS instead of HTTP, but it seems like the off-topic links (in `Flagging` > `Closing` > `Off-Topic` and in `Flagging` > `Closing` > `Off-Topic` > `Migration`) are instead HTTP.

Since visiting any of the HTTP links there immediately redirects to HTTPS, can they please be changed to HTTPS to skip the step where the browser has to redirect to HTTPS? This would speed things up slightly as well as provide a bit more security.

---

Also, the link in `Migration` tries to go to http://meta.askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, but that URL redirects to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic rather than providing a page with information on what's on-topic specifically on Ask Ubuntu Meta. Is that supposed to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, thanks!